# Saving PlayerPrefs for multiple instances

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have setup a simple shop where when the player clicks to 'BUY' a character, the item gets unlocked and stays saved as unlocked. This is in one scene (Shop scene).

I have a second scene where the character gets unlocked based on this purchase for the player to be able to select (character scene).

I am placing the scripts on empty gameObjects on each scene. It works fine when it is just buying one character. But how do I replicate this for multiple characters.

I could place the scripts on individual buttons and place corresponding gameobjects under the inspector but this would not be practical if I have like a 100 characters.

Please advice how I could make this work across multiple instances. Thought of tagging and that too doesn't seem feasible. I am open for suggestions if there is a better way of doing this. Thanks.

```
//Class controlling Shop Scene via an empty Gameobject
 public class ShopManager : MonoBehaviour 
 {
     private bool unlocked;

     public GameObject greyImg;

     void Start()
     {
         unlocked = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("unlocked") == 1;
         greyImg.SetActive(unlocked);
     }

     public void Buy()
     {
         unlocked = true;
         PlayerPrefs.SetInt("unlocked", 1);
         PlayerPrefs.Save();
         greyImg.SetActive(true);
     }
 }
```

This is how the unity setup looks for shop scene. If the item is already bought, the grey image is set to active thus not allowing the user to click the green buy button any more.

[image]

When character is unlocked/bought

[image]

```
 //Class controlling Character select scene via an empty Gameobject
 public class CharacterManager : MonoBehaviour 
 {
     private bool unlocked;
     public GameObject greySelect;

     void Start()
     {
         unlocked = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("unlocked") == 1;
     }

     void Update()
     {
         if (unlocked)
         {
             greySelect.SetActive(false);
         }
     }
 }
```

This is how Unity setup looks for Character select scene. If the character is already unlocked, the grey select image is set to inactive and the orange select button will be visible thus allowing the character to be selected.

[image]

when character unlocked

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are probably many ways in which to tackle this problem. Here's one;

You're going to need a separate player prefs entry for each character. So, you'll need a nice way to keep track of the characters you have and their unlock state. Instead of saving 'unlocked' in player prefs, why not create a class that contains unlocked information?

```
class UnlockedCharacters
{
    bool characterAUnlocked = false;
    bool characterBUnlocked = false;
    bool characterCUnlocked = true;
}
```

You can then serialize this whole class and save the whole class inside player prefs. Then, when you load your game you can load this class from player prefs to populate your character information. This way, data is managed and is consistent across saved states.

You could go one step further and keep everything relating to your characters inside of a Dictionary whereby your int is an enum referring to a character and the bool is its unlock state. You can then save/load this dictionary again using player prefs.

Inside the class you could have helper methods with your generic gameobject scripts call to keep things nice and encapsulated.

This way, your individual GameObjects which handle specific characters can hold a reference to this enum and you can use your general script to set/modify your data contents based on your enum field that you can then set via your inspector, or in initialisation code for your object.

EDIT FOR COMMENT BELOW - AN EXAMPLE:

Your generic character controller would go on the individual objects, and by changing your CHAR_TYPE the same script will work to unlock multiple characters.

```
class CharacterManager
{
    public enum CHAR_TYPE = { characterA, characterB, characterC }
    private Dictionary<CHAR_TYPE, bool> characterUnlockState;

    void Start()
    {
        // Seeding with some data for example purposes
        characterUnlockState = new Dictionary<CHAR_TYPE, bool>();
        characterUnlockState.Add(CHAR_TYPE.characterA, false);
        characterUnlockState.Add(CHAR_TYPE.characterB, false);
        characterUnlockState.Add(CHAR_TYPE.characterC, true);
    }

    public bool IsCharacterUnlocked(CHAR_TYPE character)
    {
        if (characterUnlockState.Contains(character)) return characterUnlockState[character];

        return false;
    }

    public void UnlockCharacter(CHAR_TYPE character)
    {
        if (characterUnlockState.Contains(character)) characterUnlockState[character] = true;
    }
}

class GenericCharacterController
{
    public CHAR_TYPE character;
    public CharacterManager manager;

    public void UnlockButtonPressed()
    {
        manager.UnlockCharacter(character);
    }

}
```

Comment: Individual buttons going to have to have their own public method that activates upon click. Currently all are going to have the same method, thus would end up activating all characters same time when 1 is unlocked. Other that a separate class to have saved information, how am I going to handle this. Do you mean 10 different methods, each doing a different action to activate individual characters? (I am assuming this is not what you mean but I am unable to understand how I am going to make 1 method work differently for different character unlocks). Will you be able to give an example. Tnks.

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of ways to approach this.  You are going to need an ID of some kind for each item in your store.  So I would make a StoreItem script that you place on each thing for sale.  The StoreItem script would need an ItemID property at the minimum.  Then your StoreManager could check if it's unlocked like this:

```
PlayerPrefs.GetInt(selectedStoreItem.ItemID + "_unlocked");
```

Also, while this approach would work, it's not recommended.  It's possible for playerprefs to be manipulated by the user outside of your game.  So they could potentially give themselves free items.  I don't know how important that is to you.  The better approach would be store this info on a server somewhere and have the game sync up with that to determine what items the player owns.

Comment: Say I have 10 characters, so duplicate 10x item scripts which just handle the Id and have one main script for the store that handles the rest? Cos I get the idea I would still end up having to handle each character's on/off for the grey/orange green/grey buttons by stating them as public and assigning individually. Can you give me a rough example. Can't get my head around it. Tnks.

Comment: You would create a StoreItem template object.  The template object would have public properties for all the UI elements associated with a store item (orange button etc).  After you build a prefab for the template, you would add a template property to your store manager and associate the prefab you just made with it.  You could then dynamically instantiate all the store items at runtime and maybe call a method on each StoreItem called SetCharacter(characterName);  And in that method you could check playerprefs for the name that was passed in and then change the UI elements for that item.

Comment: You can do this all dynamically by looping through your character list and creating a new StoreItem object for each.  You then just pass your character ID to the StoreItem and it will update it's own UI according to the ownership status it determines.